# Connect new folder to Heroku

Tags: git, heroku, terminal

I have my site deployed on Heroku (with some help). The person sent me all the files which I have downloaded and moved to a specific location on my laptop. I want to edit the files in this folder and update the site content, but it isn't changing the site because it's not connected to that folder.

I assume I would have to re-setup the connection with this new folder with heroku git remote.

I tried heroku git remote but I got this:

```
fatal: remote heroku already exists.
```

I tried looking for answers, asking for help, but everything I found always seemed to skip how to connect the folder. (It'd never specify how to type in the location of the desired folder to connect to.) I'm not a web developer at all so I would appreciate it if you could share what exactly I type into Terminal to re-establish the connection.

All I know is the step that once it is properly connected, I can just edit the files, save and then type in:

```
Git add .
Git commit -m “message here”
Git push origin
Git push heroku master
```

Thank you.

--

Also tried cloning

```
fatal: No configured push destination.

hint: Updates were rejected because the remote contains work that you do
hint: not have locally. This is usually caused by another repository pushing
hint: to the same ref. You may want to first integrate the remote changes
hint: (e.g., 'git pull ...') before pushing again.
hint: See the 'Note about fast-forwards' in 'git push --help' for details.

joyjoko.space $ git push heroku master
The authenticity of host 'heroku.com (#####)' can't be established.
RSA key fingerprint is #####.
Are you sure you want to continue connecting (yes/no)? yes
Warning: Permanently added 'heroku.com,#####' (RSA) to the list of known hosts.
Permission denied (publickey).
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
```

I son't understand the hints, could anyone please explain? What should I type in Terminal to get this to connect to my desired folder?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

I think you clone sample repository.
You shoud remove old remote :

```
git remote rm heroku
```

and add it again.

or use `git remote set-url heroku <your_url>` to change url.